# Multiple Objects In With Statement

Tags: vba, excel

I'm wondering why this simple code throws a "Object Required" error when I attempt to run it. I can't really find any reason why VBA would have trouble andling this. It compiles OK, but fails to run.

```
Sub Test()

Dim X, Y, Z As Range

Set X = Sheets(1).Range("A1")
Set Y = Sheets(2).Range("A1")
Set Z = Sheets(3).Range("A1")


With X And Y And Z
.Value = "Test" 'FAILS HERE
End With


End Sub
```

Im sure its something small, or maybe VBA just can't handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do this a lot, create a helper routine:

```
Sub setValueOf(value As String, ParamArray ranges())
   Dim i As Long
   For i = 0 To UBound(ranges)
      ranges(i).value = value
   Next
End Sub
```

You can then pass 1 or more ranges;

```
setValueOf "Test", Sheets(1).Range("A1"), Sheets(2).Range("A1"), Sheets(3).Range("A1"), [B5], ...
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I have a document that sets the same thing in over 50 places in different sheets, on different ranges. I just didnt want to type it all out, line after line of the same thing. This makes it much easier and nicer to view when coming back to it after months to make a change!

Comment: ++ this is quite good, but if you have more than 50 places it would also make sense to create a collection and pass a collection (*or collecitons*) to set ranges instead of individual Range references. It would also help you store all the ranges in one place -> think future editing etc.

Answer (score 3):

VBA is trying to use the result of logical 'X AND Y AND Z' as the object in your with statement, which is probably not what you want

You need:

```
X.Value = "Test"
Y.Value = "Test"
Z.Value = "Test"
```

rather than

```
(X AND Y AND Z).Value = "Test"
```

Comment: That makes sense, is there a way of achieving what I'm trying to do without setting the string value separately for each variable?

Comment: @SilverShotBee When specificly applied to ranges, there would be if your range belonged to the same worksheet: `Application.Union(X, Y, Z).Value = "Test"`. But you can't union ranges from different sheets.

Comment: If instead of `X, Y and Z` you used `X[0], X[1] and X[2]` then you could loop over the array indexes, but it would still need to perform three operations to set the values

Answer (score 2):

You could set your range values using a loop instead:-

```
Sub Test()

Dim i

For i = 1 to 3
    sheets(i).range("A1").value = "TEST"
Next  

End Sub
```